# Javascript filter function - Trying to understand it properly

Tags: javascript

I'd like some help to clarify how exactly I should be using filter.

The following works just fine:

```
let nums = [10, 12, 15, 20]
nums.filter(num => num > 14)
```

result = [15, 20]

If I understand this correctly, I'm passing in a function with num as argument.

Now here's where it all gets confusing (Keep in mind I'm not an advanced js programmer)

I have an array of html elements

```
let fields = document.getElementsByClassName("f-field")
```

Every single element in the returned array contains a bunch of other html elements, it looks something like this.

```
<div class="f-field">
     <textarea id="9008" name="Logo"></textarea>
</div>
```

The inner HTML can be textareas, selects, inputs, whatever...

I tried this and it says

### "fields.filter is not a function"

```
fields.filter(field => field.getElementsByName("Logo"))
```

I'm assuming that filter does not work for an Array of html elements. Or am I doing this wrong?

Thanks in advance, I'm trying to really understand javascript

Comment: because getElementsByClassName is not an array it is an HTML Collection

Comment: As mentioned by @epascarello, the object returned by `getElementsByClassName` is not an Array but a `HTMLCollection` object. However, you can still use `Array.prototype.filter` by manually setting the context because HTMLCollection exposes a similar interface as Array: so, `a = Array.prototype.filter.call(fields, field => /*filter predicate*/)` will work. I also want to add that the function you pass to filter in teh second example does not return a Boolean value and therefore probably does not work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DOM query methods like `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelector` return collections that are array-*like*, but not *actually* arrays (`HTMLCollection`, `NodeList`). They have numbered keys you can iterate over, and length properties too, but do not support array generics like `filter`, `forEach` or `map`.

You can cast an array-like object into an array using `array = Array.from(source)`. If you're writing ES6, you could also use the *spread operator*: `array = [...source]`

So, you could write your code as follows:

```
let fields = document.querySelectorAll('.f-field');
logos = Array.from(fields).filter(field => field.getElementsByName('logo'));
```

Then again, why do all that filtering and traversing when you could just pass a CSS selector straight to `querySelectorAll`? e.g.

```
let logos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.f-field [name="logo"]'));
```

Comment: Note, `.getElementsByClassName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList`.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about this CSS selector approach. It did work but it did not return an array, just the one textarea (exactly what I needed anyway). Question is, if it found more than one element, it would return an HTMLCollection instead?

Comment: @Lberteh if you use querySelectorAll, it will match multiple items and return them as a `NodeList` (not a HTMLCollection, to be picky). You can then cast this into an array using Array.from or the spread operator.

Answer (score 5):

Yup this is a little tricky. [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) does NOT return an Array. It returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which behaves like an array in some ways (you can iterate over it and it has a length), but does not contain most of the [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2).

Comment: ...so for anyone else who is trying to do what I am, putting it all together: `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myClass"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to an array as follows

```
var filteredFields = [...document.getElementsByClassName("f-field")].filter(item => itemTest(item));
```

Find out more about the [spread operator at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks but it is there.

Comment: Missed it initially.  Have you considered including description of usage of spread element at Answer?